# Selling SaaS products on Cloud Marketplaces (AWS / GCP / Azure)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace

I understand the only technical information that a developer needs to provide while registering a SaaS product is its entry point (URL). But is it a prerequisite to run the service on the platform in which it is being sold?

To be more specific, if I own a service that generates a story based on the current affairs in the world, do I need to be running it on AWS to be able to sell on AWS Marketplace?

I did not see this in AWS docs anywhere, but I was wondering if I maybe missing something!

How would AWS marketplace benefit from listing a SaaS product that actually runs on their competitors cloud?

Answer (score 0):

SaaS Products sold on AWs Marketplace must run on AWS:
"A portion of your application must be hosted in an AWS account that you own."
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/saas-guidelines.html

Answer (score 0):

At Close, we know how to sell SaaS. We began as Elastic, Inc., an outsourced sales solution for Silicon Valley startups. After we developed Close for internal use, we pivoted and began to sell our inside sales software to SaaS sales teams.

We’ve worked with thousands of startups and seen countless successes and failures. We know what works, and we know what doesn’t. In our experience, these are the nine cornerstones of [SaaS products](https://zaapteam.com/) sales success.